# What does __EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT_ mean?

Tags: profiler

I am using the AOE Profiler, which can be downloaded for free from http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html. Now, when I profile some pages of my store, it says stuff like:

- __EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT_
- __EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ATTR_

I an wondering what that means exactly? It also mentions the template file where that occurs, in my case it options.phtml. Can anybody tell me how to read those expressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the keys used as part of magento `Varien_Profiler`. They are used to show the entity and attribute loading times in the `Varien_Profiler`. See `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`

```
Varien_Profiler::start('__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT__');
$this->_loadEntities($printQuery, $logQuery);
Varien_Profiler::stop('__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT__');
Varien_Profiler::start('__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ATTR__');
$this->_loadAttributes($printQuery, $logQuery);
Varien_Profiler::stop('__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ATTR__');
```

Basically when you using a EAV collection and call load on this then the two functions are called. The text is simply the name given to these in `Varien_Profiler`

1. _loadEntities: Load entities records into items
2. _loadAttributes: Load attributes into loaded entities

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how could I track down the time being used by those actions? In my case, they consume a good amount of time.

Comment: @user1638055 does the profiler not do exactly that and show you how long each function takes?

Comment: Thing is, I am not using a collection in my options.phtml, thats why I am wondering. Could this also be caused by calling `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute(...)`?

Comment: well any eav collection will get to this point on load